# Why does JSDOM's `runScripts: 'dangerously'` change the output of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(jsdom.window)`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

## Update

I've yet to understand why, but the `runScripts: 'dangerously',` is causing this problem. When I comment that out, the first `console.log` prints `1`, just like a browser.

---

[I created a repository for the node.js side of this question.](https://github.com/DanKaplanSES/jsdom-sandbox/tree/jsdom-window.HTMLElement) Here's the entire `index.js` file:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

JSDOM.fromFile('template.html', {
    url: 'http://localhost',
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
    resources: 'usable',
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
}).then(({ window }) => {
    console.log(`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter((k) => k === "HTMLElement").length`, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter((k) => k === "HTMLElement").length);
    
    console.log(`window.HTMLElement`, window.HTMLElement);
    console.log(`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement')`, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement'));
    console.log(`Object.getPrototypeOf(window.constructor).name`, Object.getPrototypeOf(window.constructor).name);
});
```

Note the `0` in this code's output:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter((k) => k === "HTMLElement").length 0
window.HTMLElement [class HTMLElement extends Element]
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement') {
  value: [class HTMLElement extends Element],
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: true
}
Object.getPrototypeOf(window.constructor).name EventTarget
```

If I run those same `console.log`s in the browser, it prints `1`:

```js
console.log(`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter((k) => k === "HTMLElement").length`, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter((k) => k === "HTMLElement").length);

console.log(`window.HTMLElement`, window.HTMLElement);
console.log(`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement')`, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement'));
console.log(`Object.getPrototypeOf(window.constructor).name`, Object.getPrototypeOf(window.constructor).name);
```

As far as I can tell, these properties have the same descriptors and both `window`s have the same prototype (name). I'm not aware of anything else that could because this difference in behavior.

Why does this code work differently in JSDOM?

---

#### Miscellaneous information

I have created this GitHub issue in the JSDOM repository because it might be a bug of some sort: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3688

As far as I know, the `template.html` file is irrelevant to my question, but here's how it looks:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using jsdom 24.0.0 and node v20.10.0.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that you need `HTMLElement` to exist?

Comment: @ggorlen many scripts written for the browser refer to DOM objects. I'm trying to run a script that has this line of code: `o instanceof NodeList`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce an error being thrown on v22.0.0-nightly20240229f4af4b111c.

Comment: @guest271314 dang it. I forgot to `npm update` after installing. That said, I still get the error now that I'm using v24.0.0. BTW, why would v22.0.0 have a nightly when v24 is released?

Comment: I just fetched the Node.js nightly archive and extracted the `node` executable today. I don't have `npm` on my machine. This is what I did: `mkdir test`, `bun install jsdom`, created the template.html and index.js files, then ran `node --experimental-default-type=module index.js`. No errors were thrown.

Comment: @guest271314 my bad, I forgot to update the node example with the lines that throw the error. See my edit. I also pushed that change to the repo.

Comment: That's because `window` is not defined on `global` in `node`, or properly for JavaScript runtime interoperability outside of `node`, `globalThis`. When you include `globalThis.window = window;` before the `eval()` call no error is thrown.

Comment: @guest271314 I still get the error when I put `globalThis.window = window;` before or after the `const indirectEval = eval;` line.

Comment: I don't. `eval()` is global. `window` in your code is defined only in the `then()` callback scope, and is not global. This is what I did `globalThis.window = window; const indirectEval = eval; indirectEval(\`console.log(window.HTMLElement);\`);` which prints `[class HTMLElement extends Element]`.

Comment: @guest271314 huh. I see the same thing now that I copy and pasted your code. (Weird thing is, when I undo I see I already had the same code. Maybe I tried before VS Code's autosave took effect. *shrug*) Now that I see that works, I think I know the "jsdom way" to do that: I need to change `eval` to `window.eval` instead of the `globalThis.window = window;` line.

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks, by the way! With that out of the way, what's the explanation for the first `console.log` line being different between the two environments?

Comment: `"HTMLElement"` is not included in the `Array` returned by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)`. I am not sure how JSDOM is defining the property, it's defined though `console.log(Object.hasOwn(window, "HTMLElement"), window["HTMLElement"], window?.HTMLElement)`.

Comment: Did you mean `const indirectEval = window.eval;` instead of `const indirectEval = eval;`? The latter uses node.js' `eval`, and of course there's no `HTMLElement` in the nodejs global scope.

Comment: @Bergi I did :) I think I internalized this part of the documentation without bringing the important context with it: `That is, window.eval === eval will hold, so window.eval will not run scripts in a useful way.` This makes me wonder, is there any way to make a direct eval call in jsdom? Regardless, I still don't understand why that first line prints a different number.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Ok I actually don't know jsdom that well, I was guessing it did create its own realm (global environment) like [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) does. Regarding enumerability of `window` properties, I guess it's implemented as a `Proxy` (to emulate all the shenanigans that the dom/html5 spec came up with) and that'll mess with `getOwnPropertyNames`.

Comment: @guest271314 I figured out why your fix didn't work for me at first. You modified the last line from ``indirectEval(`console.log(HTMLElement);`);`` to ``indirectEval(`console.log(window.HTMLElement);`);``. Prefixing `window.` to all of the global variables in every script JSDOM loads is not an option for me.

Comment: Well, `eval()` won't work in your case because your `window` variable is not gloabally defined and `eval()` is global - not function scope specific. There's no `HTMLElement` defined on `node` `global` or `globalThis`. Your `console.log()` call is equivalent to `indirectEval(\`console.log(globalThis.HTMLElement);\`)` which does not exist on `node` `globalThis`.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/2f8a7302a43fff92f244d5f3426367a8eb2b8896/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js#L102-L118) answer your question?

Comment: @guest271314 `eval()` won't work but I think it's for a different reason: `eval()` is node's `eval()`, and node does not look in `window` when it tries to resolve "bare" variable name. jsdom's `eval()` was built to work differently. It *does* look in `window` to resolve "bare" variable names. By "bare" variable names, I mean variables without a `window`/`global`/`globalThis` prefix and without a `const`/`let` of that name in scope.

Comment: @guest271314 Regarding `globalThis.window = window;`, see https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/wiki/Don't-stuff-jsdom-globals-onto-the-Node-global

Comment: @Bergi I test and vet all claims in all documentation when I run the code. Claims in documentation can be wrong, misleading, technically incorrect. That is not an infrequent occurrence. Therefore it is possible I might disregard or prove wrong claims in documentations; or for my own use cases that are outside the thoughts or awareness of the folks who wrote the documentation. That said, the code in OP does not follow the suggested usage of `window.eval()`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, unfortunately, while that's straightforward on a greenfield project, following that advice can be a complete rearchitecture for others. In fact, [I don't think there is a way to run jsdom's `eval` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78085257/why-doesnt-jsdoms-object-getownpropertynameswindow-include-dom-objects?noredirect=1#comment137660261_78085257), and the code I'm working on already does that.

Comment: @DanielKaplan "*That is, `window.eval === eval` will hold, so `window.eval` will not run scripts in a useful way.*" - yes, but that does hold only for "*the default configuration, without setting `runScripts`*".  So is that part of your question solved by using `window.eval('HTMLElement')`?

Comment: @Bergi I have a way to run that last line of code without getting an error, so I believe so.

Comment: @Bergi wrt your link to the source code, it's over my head. A lot of the variables in that part are defined in other modules, so I'm not able to follow what it's doing. All of this being said, *from a JavaScript language perspective*, I don't understand how the `window` of both environments can look equivalent in this many ways except for the result of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)`. How can the property exist in `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'HTMLElement')` but not `getOwnPropertyNames`?

Comment: You said you are assuming a `Proxy`. By that do you mean jsdom is proxying `getOwnPropertyNames` incorrectly?

Comment: "*you mean jsdom is proxying `getOwnPropertyNames` incorrectly?*" - that is at least a possible explanation for the observed behaviour. I don't have the time to dig deeper in the code right now to see whether this is actually the case. Also I wonder whether `window === window.eval('window')`, i.e. whether the window (and global object) that is visible to scripts is the same object as the one the nodejs code is interacting with. If it isn't, also try `window.eval('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)')` :-)

Comment: If you don't set `runScript` then it will be there. I guess it's part of some protection, but it may be unintended.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry for the delay. `window === window.eval('window')` is `true`. `window.eval('Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)')` did not contain these DOM objects either.